# Is it legal to work for commision only in Canada?

Tags: canada, work-for-hire

I am interested in the province British Columbia, in Canada. Is it legal to work a job that pays only based on commission and has no base pay? I heard not as per something in here but am unclear if it matters if it's contract work... http://www.bclaws.ca/EPLibraries/bclaws_new/document/ID/freeside/00_96113_01

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are an employee, yes provided that you are paid at least the minimum wage for the hours worked. A contract for Y% commission but not less that $X per hour (where $X is the minimum hourly rate) would be fine.

If you are an independent contractor, yes. However, ...

### You are not an independent contractor just because you say you are!!!!!

If the nature of the relationship is overall an employee-employer one then you are an employee irrespective of if you or your employer calls you an independent contractor. See [here](http://www2.gov.bc.ca/gov/content/employment-business/employment-standards-advice/employment-standards/factsheets/employee-or-independent-contractor), indeed, the second example of "not a contractor" is a sales rep.

Comment: Why do you answer yes and then say you must be paid minimum wage?

Comment: @TwoTwins for the reasons explained- the commission must be more than you would earn on the minimum hourly rate, if so, it is fine that the basis is a commission